# Azure Data Factory (V2) Copy Activity - advanced editor missing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Background, Trying to copy data from SQLDB to Blob parquet file. This is being prevented due to a complex column type (geography). I would like to convert this to string data type.

There seems to be a way to do this by checking the "Map complex values to string" box and if that doesn't work use the advanced editor.

Such as seen here:

[image]

however, this does not exist in my Azure data factory:

[image]

ideas:

- These features need to be turned on?

but I can't find any documentation on how...

- They are available in v1 but not yet in v2

I will have to use different method (e.g. dataflow.. powerquery) to copy or different sink dataset type (it works fine with csv but I was hoping to keep the schema.

Your ideas or general thought would be appreciated.

Comment: If ANY answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the official MS docs [Data type mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#data-type-mapping)

> [image]

Also, I don't see the Data Type **geography** under currently supported ones.

> [image]

**I would suggest you try Data flow for same, using derived column and dynamic expression to set string data type.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in your case the the source you are pointing to a table in the copy activity .
[image]
You can always select the Query option and write the query , in this case it should help you by as it will help you write a SQL statemnt like

> SELECT tostring(yourgepcolumn), other cols from your table